# Testdriven.io: Scalable FastAPI Applications on AWS. "Test and code quality" question

Tags: testdriven.io

I'm going through the course *Scalable FastAPI Applications on AWS and Docker* from **testdriven.io**, but with a little challenge by using **GitHub Actions** instead of **Gitlab CI**.

In the **Part 1** -> **Tests and Code Quality** part, there is something that I don't understand.

More precisely, in the **Code Quality Checks** part.

As a reminder, here is the content of the *service-talk-booking-code-quality* job :

```yaml
service-talk-booking-code-quality:
  stage: test
  image: registry.gitlab.com/<your-gitlab-username>/talk-booking:cicd-python3.11-slim
  before_script:
    - cd services/talk_booking/
    - poetry install
  script:
    - poetry run flake8 .
    - poetry run black . --check
    - poetry run isort . --check-only --profile black
    - poetry run bandit .
    - poetry run safety check
```

And the Dockerfile of the docker container that is running this job :

```
FROM python:3.11-slim
RUN mkdir -p /home/gitlab && addgroup gitlab && useradd -d /home/gitlab -g gitlab gitlab && chown gitlab:gitlab /home/gitlab
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl
USER gitlab
WORKDIR /home/gitlab
RUN curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 -
ENV PATH=/home/gitlab/.local/bin:$PATH
RUN poetry config virtualenvs.in-project true
```

When running `cd / && ls -Rla` in the container, here is what I see :

```
2024-01-26T21:08:23.7347494Z ./__w/talk-booking:
2024-01-26T21:08:23.7347603Z total 12
2024-01-26T21:08:23.7347847Z drwxr-xr-x 3 1001  127 4096 Jan 26 21:08 .
2024-01-26T21:08:23.7348076Z drwxr-xr-x 6 1001 root 4096 Jan 26 21:08 ..
2024-01-26T21:08:23.7348380Z drwxr-xr-x 2 1001  127 4096 Jan 26 21:08 talk-booking
2024-01-26T21:08:23.7348387Z 
2024-01-26T21:08:23.7348582Z ./__w/talk-booking/talk-booking:
2024-01-26T21:08:23.7348704Z total 8
2024-01-26T21:08:23.7348920Z drwxr-xr-x 2 1001 127 4096 Jan 26 21:08 .
2024-01-26T21:08:23.7349137Z drwxr-xr-x 3 1001 127 4096 Jan 26 21:08 ..
```

There is a `talk-booking` directory, but it is empty, so no wonder why `poetry` does not work after.

My question is : **In the course, how is there a `services/talk_booking/` folder in the container since it was not copied in the Dockerfile ?**

My first guess would be to simply add a `COPY` step in the Dockerfile, but I think there is a reason there is none in the provided file.

Thank you in advances for your answers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I got it.

Turns out I needed to :

- Checkout the repository

```yaml
- name: Checkout Repository
  uses: actions/checkout@main
```

- Run the container as root

```yaml
container:
  image: kernju/my-image
  options: --user root
```